# Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function when using closures

Tags: swift, generics

I have a function like this:

```
func register<T: Routable>(_ action: Action, withCallback callback: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
    notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: actionMap[action], object: nil, queue: .main, using: { notification in
    let routable = T(userInfo: notification.userInfo)
        callback(routable)
    })
}
```

Where `Routable` is defined like:

```
protocol Routable {
    init?(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]?)
}
```

When I try to use it, I receive

> Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function

This is the usage:

```
controller.register<Navigate>(Action.navigate) { [unowned self] navigate in
    // do something
}
```

Any idea to make the compiler happy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is purely a syntax issue. You can't pass the type parameter directly like this. You need to "fill in the type hole" instead. To do that, you need to add the type to `navigate`:

```
controller.register(Action.navigate) { [unowned self] (navigate: Navigate?) in ... }
```

Sometimes that syntax is annoying because it buries the type. You can improve it by rewriting the signature of `register` this way:

```
func register<T: Routable>(action: Action, returning: T.type,
                           withCallback callback: @escaping (T?) -> Void)
```

You'd then call it this way:

```
controller.register(action: .navigate, returning: Navigate.self) { 
    [unowned self] navigate in 
    // ...
}
```

The `returning` parameter isn't directly used in the function. It just provides a more explicit way to specialize the function.

Comment: Rob, thanks you! A the end, when I was thinking on a solution, I ended up with the second one.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to say without seeing a more complete code example... but basically what the compiler is telling you is "You told me you want the register function to be generic (because it has a type parameter) but then you are also trying to tell me exactly what type to use and I don't like that".

The point at which you are "explicitly specializ[ing]" the function is when you add a specific type parameter in the call:

```
controller.register<Navigate>...
# Right Here       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The compiler wants the flexibility to determine what type of register function to call.  I suspect what you want is:

```
controller.register(Action.navigate) {...
```

Where you do not explicitly specialize the generic function but let the complier figure out which specialization to use.